# UIPickerView didSelectRow event does not return row value

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I am using a UIPickerView control for my iphone app development and am able to populate it with custom values.

I am using the following event method to obtain the chosen row

```
(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *) thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   NSInteger selectedRow = row;
}
```

The above event method is fired as soon as I select something on the `UIPickerView` but, when I hover over the variable `selectedRow` using the debugger, I do not see the value.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Subbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can type "print selectedRow" in GDB console to get the value.